# How would I show that $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

If A and B are a subset of C. I know it's true by showing examples but how is it proved?

Comment: Apply the definitions.

Comment: @arkeet you mean the definition of union? It's the fact that they are inside a function which is throwing me off. Because if you take it out of the function it's just A U B = A U B?

Comment: (Let $f \colon X \to Y$.) To show e.g. that $f(A \cup B) \subseteq f(A) \cup f(B)$, assume $y \in f(A \cup B)$ and show it's in the latter set. If you look at the definition of $f(A \cup B)$, you will see it is the set of all $y \in Y$ such that $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in A \cup B$. That is the start.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Prove both inclusions.

$f(A \cup B) \subseteq f(A) \cup f(B):$

Let $x$ in $f(A \cup B)$, there there exists $y \in A \cup B$ such that $f(y) = x$. If $y \in A$, then $x \in f(A)$, and if $y \in B$, then $x \in f(B)$, so in both cases $x \in f(A) \cup f(B)$.

$f(A) \cup f(B) \subseteq f(A \cup B):$

Let $x \in f(A) \cup f(B)$. 
If $x \in f(A)$, then there exists $y \in A$ such that $f(y) = x$. As $y$ is in $A$, it is in $A \cup B$, so $f(y)=x \in f(A \cup B)$. If $x \in f(B)$, the procedure is analogous.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

First prove $\supset$. For that, observe $A, B\subset A\cup B$.

Then prove $\subset$ taking an element $y=f(x)$, $\;x\in A\cup B$. Where can $y$ dwell?

Comment: What is the backwards subset sign?

Comment: Contains (as a subset, not as an element).